# Why is not possible to position '::after' pseudo-selector after an image?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Let's say I have something like this:

```css
    .test-container {
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .test-container::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: red;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="test-container">
   <h1>TESTE</h1>
   <h2>TESTE</h2>
   <img src="https://www.acmetek.com/wp-content/uploads/rapidssl-logo.png" />
</div>
```

As can be seen `::after` is positioned before the image and not as the last element of the div, but if I have only text inside the div `::after` is indeed positioned as the last element.

I understand that I could position `after` with `bottom` and also understand that I can't insert pseudo-selectors to image tags, but here I am using a `div` and I don't get this behavior.

What I'd like to know is why it behaves like that.

Comment: don't repeat the same question, if you are not convinced with the answer given, edit your question or ask for clarification

Comment: I added a duplicate explaining the theoretical part

Comment: I didn't repeat my question. You had already added this post to the other question I did, it didn't answer my question there and doesn't answer here.

Comment: it does, read it fully to understand. it's not about display, it's about *static position*. The display will simply affect the static position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```css
display: block;
```

to your `::after`.

Because by default, pseudo-elements are `inline` elements, and also `img` tags are `inline` as well. So they are trying to fit into the same line.

Once you make `::after` `display: block`, it will fit itself in the next line and stay at the bottom of the `img` tag as expected:

```css
.test-container {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.test-container::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: red;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-container">
   <h1>TESTE</h1>
   <h2>TESTE</h2>
   <img src="https://www.acmetek.com/wp-content/uploads/rapidssl-logo.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Now it makes sense. There was already a couple hours it was bugging me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but as has been mentioned, both the `<img>` and the `::after` pseudo-element are inline elements. As a matter of fact, you can see the same behavior if you use a plain `<span>` instead of a pseudoelement. (See below).

So I don't think this is as much a question about pseudoelements as it is about the interaction between the inline elements as they wrap around an absolute-positioned element.

Not a full answer, but maybe a step closer.

```css
    .test-container {
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .test-container2 {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: red;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="test-container">
   <h1>TESTE</h1>
   <h2>TESTE</h2>
 

   <img src="https://www.acmetek.com/wp-content/uploads/rapidssl-logo.png" />
   <span class="test-container2"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `I don't think this is as much a question about pseudoelements as it is about the interaction between the inline elements`. You're right, but it was beyond my knowledge. Now it makes sense. Thank you very much.